# Bootstrap 3: Create list with text and image left aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, icons

I'd like to create a layout like the one in the image

[image]

[large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaiex.png).

What is the best and cleanest way create the layout in HTML and the cleanest way to call it in the CSS? for example, should I create a div for each icon? This what I have tried so far:  cssdeck.com/labs/full/vqnsgldc

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us your work up to now in a JSFiddle? If not, go back to your text-editor and create something. We can help you smooth out the bumps, not create the whole thing for you.

Comment: @Rvervuurt This is what I have: http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/vqnsgldc. Sorry I didn't post it before, I just thought it was not good enough. ;x

Comment: Anything you tried is better than nothing! :) Always post what you've tried, could be you're actually rather close to a solution. I see you have an answer below that fits your needs, don't forget to +1 it and accept it as an answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should look into using [bootstrap media components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media) they offer: `Abstract object styles for building ... a left- or right-aligned image alongside textual content`.

Here's an example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cq2shm4w/) to start you off:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-left">
                <a href="#">
                  <img class="media-object" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="...">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
                Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis.
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-left">
                <a href="#">
                  <img class="media-object" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9InllcyI/PjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iNjQiIGhlaWdodD0iNjQiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2NCA2NCIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+PGRlZnMvPjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSI2NCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI2NCIgZmlsbD0iI0VFRUVFRSIvPjxnPjx0ZXh0IHg9IjEzLjQ2MDkzNzUiIHk9IjMyIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojQUFBQUFBO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsIEhlbHZldGljYSwgT3BlbiBTYW5zLCBzYW5zLXNlcmlmLCBtb25vc3BhY2U7Zm9udC1zaXplOjEwcHQ7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+NjR4NjQ8L3RleHQ+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==" alt="...">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
                Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis.
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually, would this be a best practice, if it's not really a media item?

Comment: Its a great way to float an image left or right of a text block. Your other option is to use nested rows and columns, but you must make sure that your markup is correct when doing so. I see in your example, it's a little malformed at the moment. Make sure columns add up to 12 in a single row.

Comment: @anujmay there's no requirement for rows to add to 12 unless controlling responsive breaking, even then that can be controlled by reset classes.

Answer (score 2):

As [Anuj already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30171266/819887) the [bootstrap media components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media) offer: `Abstract object styles for building ... a left- or right-aligned image alongside textual content`

If someone is looking for another option i would [try a list and change the list-style-image](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJXmOz) to use the image you would like to show

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li class="star">two</li>
  <li class="fo">Three</li>
</ul>
```

and this css

```
.foo { vertical-align: top; list-style-image: url(.foo.png...); }
.star { vertical-align: top; list-style-image: url(..star.png..); }
```

It seems that the image you posted is from [7shifts.com](http://7shifts.com/restaurant-employee-scheduling-software/). This is the markup they use and their approach looks similar.

```
<ul class="large-icon-list clearfix">    
     <li class="icon-list-sheets">
         <div class="icon-list-image"></div>
         <div class="icon-list-content">
             <h4>Title on the right from the image</h4>
             <p>Text on the right from the image</p>
         </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
     </li>

     <li class="icon-list-locations">
          .... same as above
     </li>

     <li class="icon-list-group-connect">
          .... same as above
     </li>
</ul>
```

And this css

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {content: " "; display: table;}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}
.clearfix { *zoom: 1;}

.large-icon-list {
    margin-top: 5em; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    margin-left: 8.54701%; margin-right: 8.54701%;
}

.large-icon-list li {
    min-height: 170px; width: 48.71795%;
    float: left; margin-right: 2.5641%;
    display: inline;
}

/* one class-rule for each image - here sheets */
.large-icon-list li.icon-list-sheets .icon-list-image {
  background: url("../icon-sheets.png?14....9") 
  no-repeat top center;
}

.large-icon-list li .icon-list-image {
  height: 100px; width: 23.07692%;
  float: left; margin-right: 2.5641%;
  display: inline;
}

.large-icon-list li .icon-list-content {
  width: 74.35897%; float: right;
  margin-right: 0; *margin-left: -30px;
  display: inline;
}
```